# Sharepoint Angular JS SP.Utilities.EmailProperties not sending emails to all internal recipients

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, angularjs, sharepoint-email

I am sending email notifications with Angularjs and all recipients are internal users. There is one person who is not receiving the emails and she did get it once, the first time we used the functionality, about 3 months ago, and now everyone gets the emails but her and still I always get a 200 response:
properties:

```
{__metadata: {type: "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties"}, From: "", To: {,…},…}
Body:
"<p>You have submitted a new form. Manager and IT have been notified.</p>"
From:""
Subject:"You Have Submitted a New On Boarding Form"
To:{,…}results:
["user1@domain.com", "user2@domain.com", "user3@domain.com"]
0:"user1@domain.com"
1:"user2@domain.com"
2:"user3@domain.com"
__metadata:
{type: "SP.Utilities.EmailProperties"}
```

I have tried adding other people (and it worked with them), have checked this person's permissions, have deleted and added again, but nothing seems to work.
Has anyone had this problem? Thanks!